# Ignore solidity's `Trying to override non-virtual function` Error

Tags: solidity

Can I make Solidity ignore its requirement that an overridden method requires to be virtual? So for example I want to be able to do this:

```
contract Bar {
    function toOverride() external {}
}

contract Foo is Bar {
    function toOverride() override external {}
}
```

Comment: sorry but i don't understand why you want a function to not be virtual if it will be overridden

Comment: @Rafael it's when doing a reentrancy honeypot attack, you need to implement a contract that looks innocent (so methods should not look like they will be overridden), but the contract you end up using is slightly modified. It's not crucial to be able to do this, but it would make the code look nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

According to [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#function-overriding):

> If you do not mark a function that overrides as virtual, derived
> contracts can no longer change the behaviour of that function.

except for functions defined inside interfaces.

Depending to what is your purposes, a possible workaround is:

```
contract Bar {
    function toOverride_ext() public {}
}

contract Foo is Bar {
    function toOverride() external {
        super.toOverride_ext();
    }
}
```